# How to filter in PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I can get all of the webs listed out but when I try to add Where-Object, nothing is returned. How do I get this where object working? This is SharePoint 2013.

```
$WepApp = "http://mywebapp.com/"
$site = Get-SPSite -Limit All $WepApp
$filteredWebs = $site | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Where-Object {$_.Url -like "*invest*"}
```

Comment: It seems as if -like does not work right at all. Whether i use the wildcard character or not, nothing is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer so I write my PowerShell in more of a C# style, but something like this should do what you want.

```
$webapp = "mywebapp.com"

$sites = $webapp | Get-SPSite -Limit All
foreach($site in $sites)
{
    foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
    {
        if($web.Url -like "*invest*")
        {
            Write-Output "Found $($web.Url)";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is perfectly working. Don't forget to print the contents of your *$filteredWebs* variable :)
You can also use **AllWebs** method:

```
$webApp = "http://mywebapp.com"
$site = Get-SPSite -Limit All $webApp
$filteredWebs = $site.AllWebs | ? {$_.Url -like "*invest*"}
$filteredWebs
```